# Number of subgroups of index 2 in $(C_2)^3\times C_3$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I need to count the number of subgroups of index 2 in $(C_2)^3\times C_3$.

I think there are 3, because we have to take $C_3$ and then we have 3 choices for a $C_2$ not to pick. However, a classmate of mine said there are 7.

In this question [Find all subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{24})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189032/find-all-subfields-of-mathbbq-mu-24) , the reader counts the number of subgroups of order 4 of $C_2^3$. I cannot follow his reasoning.

How to do this?

Comment: Yes, you have to include the $C_3$, so the answer is the same as for the number of index $2$ subgroups of $(C_2)^3$. The correct answer is indeed $7$. Try and think of some more yourself!

Comment: And note that the number of subgroups of index $2$ is the same as the number of homomorphisms of $C_2^3$ onto $C_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches:

1) You want a subgroup $H < G$ with $|G|/|H|=2$. So $H$ has order $12$. Certainly $C_3$ is contained in $H$, so $H = A \times C_3$, where $A$ is a subgroup with $4$ elements of $(C_2)^3$. How many possibilities are there for $A$? Well, any two distinct elements $a, b$ of $(C_2)^3$ generate a subgroup of order $4$, namely $\{1, a, b , ab\}$. There are $7$ elements of order $2$ in $(C_2)^3$, but note that ($a,b$), ($a,ab$) and ($b,ab$) generate the same subgroup! So the total number is $\frac{1}{3} {7 \choose 2} = \frac{1}{3}\frac{7 \cdot 6}{2} = 7 $

2) Since your group $G$ is abelian, all subgroups are normal, so any subgroup of index $2$ can be realised as the kernel of a (surjective) homomorphism $\phi: G \to C_2$. Evidently, since $\phi(C_3)=1$ because there is no element of order $3$ in $C_2$, the number of homomorphisms is the same as the number of elements of order $2$ in $G$, that is, $7$.